# python requests 'connection reset by peer' error

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using python requests to send documents to an api and then receiving scores based on these documents. My program has previously worked perfect, however I have just updated my program to send documents to two endpoints. It now runs fine for 10-15 minutes but will eventually stop with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1344, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 306, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 267, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 720, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 400, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1344, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 306, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 267, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ciaranmoran/PycharmProjects/combase_lenticular_py_scripts/testing.py", line 21, in <module>
    NER_request = requests.post(NER_Endpoint, files=files2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 116, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Is there an obvious solution to this problem? if not what steps can I take to diagnose the problem.

cheers in advance